# PDO query only returning 1 row

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to PHP and was wondering why my like query is only returning one value.

Here is my Model

```
//For search
public function getSearchResults($username){
    $stmt = $this->_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username");
    $stmt->execute(['username' => '%'.$username.'%']);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "User");
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Then in my controller

```
function search($name){

    //Get search results
    $searchResults = $this->model('User');
    $searchResults = $searchResults->getSearchResults($name);
    $data = (array) $searchResults;

    $this->view('User/search', $data);
}
```

However, it is only returning 1 result rather than 3. (I have 4 usernames with "hi" inside it, but it's only returning one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) - this only returns the one row, to return all of the rows from the result set use [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```